# How to call a compiled fortran exe file in a deployed Matlab exe in Linux?

Tags: linux, matlab, fortran, environment-variables, executable

I am trying to use a deployed Matlab exe file in Linux, and in the middle of my matlab code I want to call a .exe file compiled by Fortran.

I have tested that the fortran-compiled binary exe file is alright to run in Linux and get my results both by directly calling it in commmand line and in Matlab by 'system(read_results.exe)'. But when I deployed the Matlab code, and call it by the following command:

```
./matlab_code.sh /cm/shared/apps/Matlab-R2019a
```

The Fortran .exe file cannot be called correctly and gives the following message:

*Possible reason:read_results.exe: error while loading shared libraries: libgfortran.so.5: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory*

I guess this problem shoulbe be relatived with the environment variables or something like that. I don't know how to add those libraries to a deployed Matlab code, or how to compile the Fortran code to a totally independent binary file in Linux. Could anyone please help me with it? Thank you guys very much!!!!

( The reason I need to call a .exe file is I really cann't compile it to a DLL...So I have to use it in such a terrible way. )

Comment: Try building your fortran executable with the option **-static-libgfortran**.  Is the matlab machine different from the gfortran machine?